# Store Vault secrets in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to store the Vault `kv` in an AWS S3 bucket.

I deployed Vault in Kubernetes using Helm and also enabled the Kubernetes auth methods.

In the Helm chart `values.yaml` I have all the credentials required for S3,

```
vault:
 config:
  storage:
   s3:
    access_key: "AWS-ACCESS-KEY"
    secret_key: "AWS-SECRET-KEY"
    bucket: "AWS-BUCKET"
    region: "eu-central-1"
```

If I use this configuration locally then it works.

Can somebody please provide any working examples for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What Vault Helm chart are you using?

Comment: @Rico https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/vault